# What does object?.Property mean in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I recently came across this while going through someone else's code

```
var name = Product.Buyer?.FirstName + " " + Product.Buyer?.LastName;
```

What does this(`?.`)mean in c#

Comment: (I've tried to find a duplicate, but failed. Not so easy to search for, although I'm sure there *are* very similar questions.)

Comment: Jon Skeet Commented on my question :) . Wow

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The operator `?.` is called *Null-conditional Operators*, which is introduced in `C# 6.0`.

> Used to test for null before performing member access (?.) or index
>   (?[) operation. These operators help you write less code to handle
>   null checks, especially for descending into data structures.

see the documentation and an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn986595.aspx)